# Преобразование JSON-массива в таблицу пары ключ/значение

Tags: json, postgresql, преобразование

Есть такой массив JSONB

> select '{"title": "Отчёт1", "filters": [{"name": "Дата с", "value":
>   "01.01.1999", "property": "datebeg"}, {"name": "Дата по", "value":
>   "31.01.1999", "property": "dateend"}], "selection": [{"name": "Код",
>   "index": 0, "orderby": null, "property": "Id", "isvisible": true},
>   {"name": "Наименование", "index": 1, "orderby": 1, "property": "Name",
>   "isvisible": false}]}'::jsonb->'filters'

```
Вытащил filters и получил
```

> [{"name": "Дата с", "value": "01.01.1999", "property": "datebeg"},
>   {"name": "Дата по", "value": "31.01.1999", "property": "dateend"}]

Не подскажете, как получить массив снизу из того, что наверху

> {"datebeg": "01.01.1999", "dateend": "31.01.1999"}

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать jsonb_populate_recordset

```
select *  from (select * from jsonb_populate_recordset(null::tp_filters, (select '{"title": "Отчёт1", "filters": [{"name": "Дата с", "value": "30.01.1999", "property": "datebeg"}, {"name": "Дата по", "value": "31.01.1999", "property": "dateend"}], "selection": [{"name": "Код", "index": 0, "orderby": null, "property": "Id", "isvisible": true}, {"name": "Наименование", "index": 1, "orderby": 1, "property": "Name", "isvisible": false}]}'::jsonb->'filters'))as filter) as prop
```

Всё оказалось очень легко